# How can I replace "more and more" in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-request

I'm pretty sure "more and more" is quite informal but I can't think of anything better.

> ...to warn readers that if you give someone a taste of power, they will want more and more until...

Comment: What context is this in? A research paper? A novel? A philosophical or self-help book for the general public?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Brian! This question could be related: "*[Any other words for 'more and more'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124979/is-there-any-other-word-that-means-more-and-more)*".

Comment: It's a novel analysis

Answer (score 4):

In this sort of context there's really nothing wrong with saying "more and more". It's a serviceable phrase without much to make it stand out wrong in most cases. The only issue would be if you need [the impression of] greater precision in exactly *how much* more and perhaps in what ways, but when analyzing a novel, precise quantization is just not a concern.

Answer (score 3):

How about "they will want increasingly more power" or "they will want ever more power"?

Comment: “increasingly more” seems redundant (though I can imagine an interpretation that isn't).  “ever more” is somewhat highfalutin; I'm not confident that all of my neighbors would understand it right away.